# Unable to launch host my site as https in AWS ec2 instance

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, https, apache2, virtualhost

I'm running a ubuntu instance on AWS EC2. I'm trying to configure my default ec2 public DNS under HTTPS. I created all the required files(.crt, .key & .csr) following the steps provided at [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/openssl-essentials-working-with-ssl-certificates-private-keys-and-csrs) blog

I changed the 000-default.confg file to as below

`# The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        ServerName ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/abc`

```
    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /ssl-certificates/testing.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /ssl-certificates/testing.key
   SSLCertificateChainFile /ssl-certificates/testing.crt
```

Even after this i'm unable to open my site in https

Answer (score 0):

If you are still getting the http version,make sure that you are listening on port 443.If you haven't edited your config file to listen on 443,just replace `<VirtualHost *:80` with `<VirtualHost *:443>`.
Also I think since you're using aws,you need to expose your 443 port to the internet if its not already done by default.

Comment: I've configure to listen on 443. But still i'm facing the same issue. And how to expose 443 port to the internet? I've kept the code <IfModule ssl_module>Listen 443</IfModule> in port.confg

Comment: You can open your 443 port from the AWS dashboard,it's been a while since  I used AWS,but I believe they are within something labelled security groups,you need to click on the security group,and then add a rule to allow traffic on port 443.
Also is there any error you're getting?
Or are you just redirected to `http` version even if you enter `https://`

Comment: Thank you. changing security groups policy for ec2 instance fixed it. I was scratching my head for two days. Thanks a lot.